# Grails high memory usage Process.waitForProcessOutput

Tags: grails, memory-management

I am analyzing the memory consumption in my grails application.
I often start bash scripts with java.lang.Process
So I have a command string, create the process with

```
Process p = cmd.execute()
def stdOut = new StringBuilder()
def stdErr = new StringBuilder()
p.waitForProcessOutput(stdOut, stdErr)
```

I monitor the memory usage with

```
MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean()
MemoryUsage memoryUsage = mbean.getHeapMemoryUsage()
```

I mark the memory before execute and after waitForProcessOutput
Sometimes the memory used increases there by 50MB for bash scripts which does return only a few characters.

I want to know why the JVM Memory usage increases here so high for a Process executed in bash?

Comment: FYI... The answer I provided addressed the 2 questions above but I have deleted it in response to OP clarifying what he/she is really after which is "why the JVM Memory increases".

Answer (score 0):

A good tool to see the memory being used by your app/script AND JAVA is bpytop https://snapcraft.io/bpytop

Alan Pope of Ubuntu just tweeted this the other day and I used it and it's AWESOME! You can see the mem, cpu usage, perc of each core used, num of threads spawned by each process (as they are spawned).

It is a great tool for testing stuff like this!

Comment: Here a pic of the tool : https://twitter.com/popey/status/1316430393671901184/photo/1

Comment: What I am wondering is, why the JVM Memory increases, when there is just a little output from the process?

Comment: May have something to do with the class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html ) : 'By default, the created process does not have its own terminal or console.' So I am assuming it has to create a console/terminal to run the command.

Comment: As of 1.5, ProcessBuilder.start() is the preferred way to create a Process. Heres a good example : https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-processbuilder-api